# What's the benefits of TDD from project management point of view?

Tags: tdd

who learning more deeply about TDD, I clearly see the benefits of writing test first from a software engineering point of view. Could someone tell me, what should I say to my project manager, when I propose the idea to switch for TDD?

What are the benefits of TDD on a project management level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few advantages for project managers as it applies to TDD.

1. Bugs are notorious for knocking a project off schedule.  Things seem to be going smoothly until the end of the project, when the developers and QA team start working together to find and fix all these issues.  It isn't uncommon to find issues that require major refactoring, eating up time and resources.  TDD helps mitigate this by enforcing testing from the beginning and throughout the project.  It won't catch all the bugs, but the list will be more manageable, and that makes Project Managers very happy.
2. With the proper tools project managers can track productivity and code quality with TDD.  At any time she can see that status of the project as it applies to tests being written, and how many are passing and failing.  This quantifier helps the project manager gauge where the developers, and indeed the entire team, are in the project.  Project Managers love this sort of stuff
3. TDD helps project managers identify areas where the team may be weak or not performing well.  If you have a developer who isn't working well or keeping up, he knows early on and can address the issue before it begins to affect the product schedule.

[Here's](https://www.agileconnection.com/article/test-driven-design-project-manager) a decent article about the subject.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so easy to convince project managers to go with TDD and may be developers can use TDD even without informing PMs about it.

But I guess such points can be helpful:

1. It gives you 100% code coverage, that decreases probability of bugs (just decrease, but not eliminate it at all).
2. It pushes you towards following YAGNIE principle, so you don't write any code you don't need right now.
3. It helps you to decrease or even eliminate over-design, over-complication and premature optimization.

Comment: exactly, why ask? Just do it. It's like asking for permission to write unit-tests...? Do you also need to ask permission to write a if-statement. :-) If you hire a carpenter, do you expect them to ask you for permission to use the hammer? Just do it, and blew their minds!

Comment: @Jocke While I agree with you in principle, if working in an agile environment Karoly will be asked what s/he did and what s/he is going to do.  Answering truthfully will let the PM know that TDD is being applied when it may be frowned upon in their company.